# C's weird pointer arithmetics

Tags: c, pointers

I have a very stupid question, I just can't answer.
Can somebody tell me why the following code works?

```
char hello[]="Hello World\n";
char *hptr = hello;
while(*hptr)
{
 printf("%c", *hptr++);//here the output must be "ello World", but C thinks otherwise!!!
}
```

Comment: Nothing weird in C's pointer arithmetic. Just learn about post increments: `p++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a post-increment:

```
*hptr++
```

This uses the value of `hptr` first, and then increments it. If you wanted to skip the first letter, you would use a pre-increment:

```
*++hptr
```

This increments the pointer value, *then* uses it as a function argument.

Comment: @Mettwurst: In that case,you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
char hello[]="Hello World\n";
```

In this hello hold the address of the first index of the character array
    char *hptr = hello;
here the character pointer hptr=address of the first index of your character array 
    while(*hptr)
    {
    printf("%c", *hptr++);
    }

and in this loop it first prints the character at your first index of the character array and then increments it and then increments the address of hptr and then the second character is printed and this goes on till u reaches the null character.